# Sails - Why I'm only receiving socket updates from CRUD "shortcuts"?

Tags: javascript, websocket, sails.js

**Sails 1.0.2**

I have a `Printer` model and this code on the client side:

```
io.socket.get('/printer/find', function (data) {
    console.log(data); // display all the printers, that's ok
});

io.socket.on('printer', function (notification) {
    console.log(notification);
});
```

Then in a controller, I'm updating a printer:

```
await Printer.update({
    token: inputs.token
}).set({
    status: inputs.status
});
```

When I execute the controller code (submitting a form, for example) I'm not receiving any notification (even if the controller it's being executed from another tab or from another incognito window).

But If I update a printer from a CRUD "shortcut" route instead (visiting `http://localhost:1337/printer/update/1?status=ready` in the browser), it works:

> {verb: "updated", data: {…}, id: 1, previous: {…}}

Of course, I could do `Printer.publish(...)` to solve this, but I want to know why it's behaving like this and if there's a way to publish automatically without using the CRUD "shortcut" routes.

Comment: This may be helpful - official Sails documentation on socket usage:

https://sailsjs.com/documentation/reference/web-sockets/socket-client

https://sailsjs.com/documentation/reference/web-sockets/socket-client/sails-socket